# javascript google maps api - dynamic search place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

i've done like this video has shown but something just not working. mine not showing the place i seaching for and the marker also didnt move to that place. [Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2n_r0NDekgc)

and this is my code

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),{
    center:{
      lat:-7.9666,
      lng:112.6326
    },
    zoom:15 
  } );
  var marler = new google.maps.Marker({
    position:{
      lat:-7.9666,
      lng:112.6326
    },
    map:map,
    draggable:true  
  });
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('mapsearch'));
  google.maps.event.addListener (searchBox, 'places_changed', function(){
     var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

     var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
     var i, place;
     for (i=0; place=places[i];i++){
      //console.log(place.geometry.location);
      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location); 
      marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
     }
     map.fitBounds(bounds);
     map.setZoom(15);
  });
```

problem starts from `var searchBox` line down below 
im using `libraries=places` at the end of google api script.
thanks for your help :beer

Answer (score -1):

viola, i actually have a typo for the `marker` that written as `marler`.
case close everyone, 
you should go to that youtube tutorial, that works!